# Gradle: how to resolve dependencies to a specific folder

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

In Gradle, I'd like to take all the `compile` and `runtime` dependencies closure and have the entire (transitive) dependency graph resolved/copied to a specific folder on my file system.

Let's say this folder is `~/mydeps`.

How can I tell Gradle to fetch all the appropriate libs from the local Gradle cache (or remotely) and copy them to this folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "${System.getProperty("user.home")}/mydeps"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter Niederwieser (+1) - just trying to learn more about Gradle here: where do the `from` and `into` DSL methods come from, the `type` (Copy)? I assume I can't just reference those methods inside any old task, yes? More generally, does the `type` field act as like a parent "class" for the task, so kind of link `Task CopyDeps extends Copy`? Thanks again!

Comment: `tasks.copyDeps instanceof Copy` holds. See `Copy` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).